# MySQL #1054 error during table archiving/copying

Tags: mysql

I am trying to archive a table off by copying it's data to another database on the same server. It gives me a headache copying between databases, so I exported the table and tried to import it into the archive database. When I do that it gives me the following error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'showorder' in 'field list'
```

This happens whether I build a exact (including the showorder column with same properties) copy, or just try to straight import it. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any assistance would be helpful.

Error
SQL query:

--

### -- Database: `db_cherry`

--

### -- Dumping data for table `product`

INSERT INTO `product` (`p_id`, `cat_id`, `cat_name`, `midas_ref_code`, `product_name`, `product_des`, `spanish_name`, `prd_img_path`, `prd_img_name`, `prd_id`, `prd_price`, `prd_quantity`, `prd_add_date`, `prd_modify_date`, `prd_avail_date`, `prd_weight`, `prd_length`, `prd_width`, `prd_height`, `prd_sales`, `featured`, `status`, `main_cart`, `vip_cart`, `tax_id`, `showorder`) VALUES
('', '31', '', 0, '', '', '', '', '', NULL, 0.00, 0, '2015-09-03 17:29:03', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '', '', '', '', 0, '', 'Active', '', '', '', 0),
('0039', '6', 'The Candy Store', 2, '0039 Chocolate Caramel Squares', 'Caramel inside milk chocolate shells. Boxed. 6 oz. ', 'Cuadritos de Chocolate con Caramelo', '../images/products/detail/', '0039.jpg', NULL, 9.50, 721, '2014-09-15 20:15:18', '2016-05-27 08:23:05', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 1129, 'Not Active', 'Not Active', 'No', '[...]

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1054 - Unknown column 'showorder' in 'field list'

Comment: show the `create table` on both sides, as well as the exact query causing this error.

Comment: I used the PhpMyAmin Import function. I was in the archived table, then I used the import function, and this was the error that kicked out.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add that there are 26 items in the table. Even when I import the data and structure to create a new table it bounces it.